# Is Axiom of Choice equivalent to its version for families of sets, indexed by ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, ordinal-numbers, independence-results

Is Axiom of Choice equivalent to the following statement?

> **Axiom of Ordinal Choice:** For any ordinal $\lambda$ and any indexed family of sets $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\lambda}$ there exists a function $f:\lambda\to\bigcup_{\alpha\in\lambda}X_\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha)\in X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in\lambda$?

Comment: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~hrubin/JeanRubin/Papers/WO-choice.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140508/how-strong-is-the-axiom-of-well-ordered-choice

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you for the link. Does the well-ordered connection of sets $C(WO,\infty)$  in their paper mean the same as in my question?

Comment: Yes, I believe it does.

Answer (score 9):

It is strictly weaker than choice. This is explained in [Asaf Karagila's answer at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140508/how-strong-is-the-axiom-of-well-ordered-choice): the $L(\mathbb{R})$ of $L$ + $\aleph_1$-many Cohen generics witnesses this.

(There the principle is phrased for well-ordered index sets, but you can always pass from a well-ordered index set to an ordinal index set.)

---

As Taras Banakh comments below, there is a superficially-similar fact: namely that over NBG without global choice, global choice is equivalent to $Ord$-indexed choice. The proof is simple: for $\alpha\in Ord$ let $C_\alpha$ be the set of well-orderings of $V_\alpha$. From a choice sequence $(\triangleleft_\alpha)_{\alpha\in Ord}$ we get a well-ordering of $V$ as follows: set $x\prec y$ iff $rk(x)<rk(y)$ or $rk(x)=rk(y)$ and $x\triangleleft_{rk(x)}y$.

Note the key role of *set-sized* choice above. More abstractly (and being a bit sloppy with details), what's being used here is that in NBG without global choice every class is "locally well-orderable" in the sense of being a well-ordered union of well-orderable sets (via Foundation plus Set-Choice). We deduce global choice from well-ordered-class choice by first applying WOCC to well-order the locally-well-ordered indexing class of our global choice instance, and then applying WOCC to *that*.

However, in ZF we don't have anything like this. For example, amorphous sets are not locally well-orderable in the relevant sense. Instead, we get the following:

> (ZF) Suppose $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal and full choice holds in $V_\alpha$ for each $\alpha<\lambda$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> - Every $s\in (V_\lambda\setminus\{\emptyset\})^\lambda$ has a choice function.
> - $V_\lambda$ is well-orderable.

Comment: Very interesting. My question was motivated by a (simple) observation that the Axiom of Global Choice in NBG is equivalent to the standard AC + Axiom of choice for families indexed by the class of all ordinals. (Yhis follows from von Neumann cumulative hierarchy).

Comment: @TarasBanakh I've added a bit about why that analogy breaks down.